# Como marcar os options no retorno do ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select, option

Eu tenho um array de **ids** e estou devolvendo esse array na reposta do ajax. Como comparar esse array com os options do select e marcar o option caso ele corresponda ao índice do array?

Em PHP, usamos a função **in_array()**

```
var options = data.options;
var checkeds = data.checkeds;

$.each(options, function(i, item){
    $('#ajax_locals').append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text : item,
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas mais uma opção utilizando jQuery, percorrendo as `'options'` e verificando se o valor da `'option'` percorrida está dentro da array:

```js
var arr = ["valor1","valor2",'valor5'];

$('select').find('option').each(function (i) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var $val = $this.val();
   if($.inArray($val, arr) !== -1){
    $this.prop('selected',true);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple='true'>
  <option value="valor1">Valor1</option>
  <option value="valor2">valor2</option>
  <option value="valor3">valor3</option>
  <option value="valor4">valor4</option>
  <option value="valor5">valor5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode percorrer os `options` e marcar o que existir no *array*:

```js
let array = [4, 5, 3, 7];

$("option").each((idx, item) => {
  
  array.indexOf(Number(item.value)) > -1 ? item.selected = true : item.selected = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```